# Messed up fields when passing csv files to elastic+kibana

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, elk

I'm trying to pass csv files to elastic using the logstash plugin via HTTP.
When I look at what I have in the database I see that the fields have been messed up, the csv file is correct.
Also another thing I see is that along with the data for each entry I also get http headers, I'd prefer not to have them but anyway I could live with them. Could they be the cause of the problem?

I copy the first line of the csv file and what I get in elastic.

```
Job, BuildId, Start time, Stop time, Execution time, Queue time, Executor, Result, Parent, User
DpiTools_Admin_CleaningEselnlx_v0.1.0, 32449, 2020-02-18T01:12:010100, 2020-02-18T01:12:020100, 1.144, 0.096, eselnlx2475-Admin., SUCCESS., DpiTools_Admin_CleaningEselnlx_v0.1.0, None
```

Then What I get in elastiv as seen in kibana is:

```
Result: None Executor: DpiTools_Admin_CleaningEselnlx_v0.1.0 Stop_time: 0.236 @version:1 @timestamp:February 18th 2020, 11:17:53.455 BuildId: 32449 Execution_time: eselnlx2578-Admin. Stop_date: 0.100 Start_time: 2020-02-18T01:12:010100 Start_date: 2020-02-18T01:12:010100 headers.http_host:127.0.0.1:5044 headers.request_path:/ headers.http_version:HTTP/1.1 headers.connection:Keep-Alive headers.request_method:PUT headers.http_user_agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT; Windows NT 10.0; es-ES) WindowsPowerShell/5.1.17763.771 headers.content_length:3166 headers.http_accept: - Job:label=eselnlx2578-Admin message:label=eselnlx2578-Admin, 32449, 2020-02-18T01:12:010100, 2020-02-18T01:12:010100, 0.100, 0.236, eselnlx2578-Admin., SUCCESS., DpiTools_Admin_CleaningEselnlx_v0.1.0, None Queue_time: SUCCESS. host:172.19.0.1 _id:z0bNV3ABGO94josV3Kjr _type:doc _index:job-executions _score:1
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I forgot I had the csv headers in the configuration, from a previoues version u had date and time in two fields and now they are in the same one, that's why all got messed up.